# Update Command not firing after Edit/Save

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, formview, edititemtemplate, updatecommand

I have a page that is not firing the update command when making changes to the information.  I have several other pages that are working just fine and I am not seeing a difference in the coding that would cause the Update to not fire when selecting 'Save' button on the EditTemplate. The page works moving from the ItemTemplate to EditTemplate just fine, just not saving changes.

Here is the associated code.  This has me boggled.  I would rather not have to backend program this - rather allow the tools work as intended.  I am just not seeing the issue, any help is appreciated.

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FVClient"  runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemUpdated="FVClient_ItemUpdated">
     <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        <div class="clear-fix col-md-12">
           <div class="form-group"> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" />
              <asp:LinkButton ID="HomeButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Home" Text="Home" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" PostBackUrl="~/" />
           </div>
        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate >
            ...
             <div class="form-group">
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" Enabled="true" />
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-primary" />
             </div>
           </div>
   </EditItemTemplate>

 </asp:FormView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbc %>"
     SelectCommand="..." 
     UpdateCommand="Exec MyStoredProc @ID, @sName, @sCode, @sAddr1, @sAddr2, @sCity, @sState, @sZip, @sContact, @sPhone1, @sPhone2, @sEmail, @sAltEmail, @sNotes, 1"
     >                          
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="ID" SessionField="client" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID"  Type="Int32" SessionField="client" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sName"  Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sCode"  Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sAddr1"  Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sAddr2"  Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sCity"   Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sState"  Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sZip"    Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sContact" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sPhone1" Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sPhone2" Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sEmail"  Type="String"  />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sAltEmail" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="sNotes"  Type="String" />                              
     </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Not sure why this was a problem maybe someone can explain it to me.  What I ended up doing was removing the `<UpdateParameters>` and it started working.

WHY??